# How to use a variable and an array in options_for_select in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-select

I'm working on the edit view for a model, and I have several option tags.

I want to see the current value displayed in the option tag and to be able to change it in case I want to.

```
<%= f.select :base_agradecimiento, options_for_select([@student.base_agradecimiento, $paquete[:base][:tipo].each do |x| [x] end]),{}, {:id => 'req_agrad'} %>
```

I'm trying to show the current value of `base_agradecimiento` and the other options in case I want to edit it but it doesn't seem to work. All I can see is the current value and not the array of options.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're after.  Try this...

```
<%= f.select :base_agradecimiento, [@student.base_agradecimiento, @paquete[:base][:tipo]].flatten, {}, {:id => 'req_agrad'} %>
```